# Rails active record query to string

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I have the AR query like this :

```
MyModel.joins(:related_model).where('related_model.some_column = ?', 'somevalue')
```

If I used `to_sql` on the above code it would generate something like :

```
"SELECT * FROM MY_MODEL INNER JOIN RELATED_MODEL ON RELATED_MODEL.SOME_ID = MY_MODEL.SOME_ID WHERE RELATED_MODEL.SOME_COLUMN = 'SOMEVALUE'"
```

I'm creating a slightly, or way more complex query, and I hate to duplicate code. Is there are way that I can get this part with some command to alter the generated SQL below?

```
INNER JOIN RELATED_MODEL ON RELATED_MODEL.SOME_ID = MY_MODEL.SOME_ID WHERE RELATED_MODEL.SOME_COLUMN = 'SOMEVALUE'"
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Could you add a sample with how you would reuse that part?

Comment: did my example below help at all? Just curious if it fits what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = MyModel.joins(:related_model).where('related_model.some_column = ?', 'somevalue').to_sql`

core_sql = foo.sub(/^SELECT * FROM MY_MODEL /,'')`
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is not what I had in mind. There has to be something that turns .joins into a join statement and .where to where statement, I'd rather not do this like you suggested, simply because this is not flexible enough solution.

Comment: OK no worries.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think will end up needing to be a method of some sort with arrays (or a `struct` or `hash` if you want to get more complex).

Using the `table_name` method to access the underlying table behind a model you could do something like this.

```
def auto_joins (primary_model, related_models, values)
   search = primary_model + '.table_name'
   primary_table_name = eval(search)
   primary_id = primary_table_name + '_id'
   output_sql = "SELECT * FROM #{primary_table_name}"
   related_models.each do |model|
       search = model + '.table_name'
       table_name = eval(search)
       output_sql += " INNER JOIN #{table_name} ON #{table_name}.#{primary_id} = #{primary_table_name}.id "
   end
   output_sql += "WHERE 1 = 1 " #overcome no values passed in...
   values.each do |where|
        output_sql += "AND #{where}"
   end
   output_sql
end
```

And in my test database I had contact that `had_many` `leads` and `prospects` I called it like this:

```
auto_joins('Contact', ['Lead', 'Prospect'], ["contact.first_name = 'Brian'"])
```

and it generated this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts 
  INNER JOIN leads ON leads.contacts_id = contacts.id  
  INNER JOIN prospects ON prospects.contacts_id = contacts.id 
  WHERE 1 = 1 AND contact.first_name = 'Brian'
```

If you wanted to take it further you could have a hash for `{model: 'Contact', where: "first_name = 'Brian'"}` and both the where and joins together based on that.

**Edit Note:** Evals are unsafe if you are exposing any of this to user input. You could find another way to access these models through `activerecord` and accomplish the same goal.